# Wordpress plugin changes not updating

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I do some changes on a plugin on my blog and for some reason it's not updating. I purge the cache on Total cache, go browser icognitno, clear cache on cloudflare. Not sure what else to do.

Comment: What plugin? Where did you make changes?

Comment: @AntonLukin I edited my question

Comment: It is not question related, but what do you think about clearing in boite-blue class? This way https://pastebin.com/FTFUHLi6

Comment: Did you try to delete plugin files and re-send after a while?